# Android, Getting inconsistency in User Current Location.?

Tags: google-play-services

I am new in android and wanna get user current location using GPS_PROVIDER, but every time getting different-different location how can I use Google Play Services. and what is the best way to get accurate location in android.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are two different types of locations available through the Android API.

One is the **GPS-Location** which only works outdoors and which has an accuaracy between 5m and 50m.

The other kind of location is the so called **Network-Location** which is a loaction measure based on Wifi Networks in you surrounding and GSM-Base-Stations which have a accuracy between 100m and 1500m. This localization technique also works indoors, because it only requires you smartphone to have network access. The accuaracy gets better in urban areas where a lot of Wifi and GSM-Base-Stations are located. The more GSM-Base-Station / Wifi hotspos are available the better is the accurarcy of the loation measurement. It can also get down to 5m.

When requesting such an location Google does internally some magic to compute the position. This request requires a internet connection (you don't need to explicitly give the permission). Interanally Android sends a request to a Google server which contains fingerprints of the surrounding GSM-Base-Stations and afterwards computes your location (if you are curious you can find the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/location/LocationManager.java#LocationManager)).
With GPS-bases location the location accurarcy is the same all over the world without any internet connection, but works only outdoors.

With my applications I implemented a logic which detects if GPS is present or not and if not I switched to network localization, this works fine.